# Pointwise convergence of partial sums of $f\in\mathit{L}(\mathbb{T})$

Tags: limits, fourier-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

Let $f\in\mathit{L}(\mathbb{T})$. Suppose that

$$|f(x)-f(0)|\leq\frac{1}{(\log(|x|))^2},\;\;0\neq x\in\left[\dfrac{-1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2}\right]$$

**Question**

Is it true that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n f(0)=f(0)$?

My guess is that it is not true but i can't seem to think of a counter-example. Any hints?

Comment: At present the LHS is zero in your inequality. Please check.

Comment: @LostStatistician18 Thank you! Corrected it